# Disable compile out

Tags: c++, c, g++, clang, compiler-optimization

Is there a way to instruct g++ or clang not to compile out variables that are not being used in the code? I know that most compilers would compile out parts of the code that do not affect the final output. For debugging reasons, I wanted to know if there is a way to disable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In gcc (and probably clang, too) you can compile with `-O0`. This will disable all optimizations. You can also use `-Og`, which should not remove variables. This flag turns on only the "debugger-friendly" optimizations.

Comment: You should combine -Og with -g to instruct the compiler to retain debug symbols.

Comment: -O flags and -g flag are separate. -g is very useful when a bug only happens at higher optimization levels.

Answer (score 2):

Simply declare the variable `volatile`.  This has the advantage of working on any compiler without the need for compiler specific extensions or command line options - it also allows you to be specific about which variables get this treatment.  If you want to be able to remove the volatile for release builds you could use the following:

```
#if defined NDEBUG
    #define DEBUG_VOLATILE
#else
    #define DEBUG_VOLATILE volatile
#endif
```

Then declarations such as:

```
DEBUG_VOLATILE debug_var = 0 ;
```

will be volatile only in debug builds.

Comment: I don't see any reason why the compiler couldn't remove a volatile variable if it's unused?

Comment: @Voo:  I think this is a case of *"in practice"* rather than *"by language definition"*.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
   int foobar __attribute__((used));
```

The documentation http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html says (emphasis added):

> This attribute, attached to a variable with the[sic] ***static*** storage, means that the variable must be emitted even if it appears that the variable is not referenced.

***Update 1:*** Perhaps this is a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem That is, what is the problem you are actually trying to resolve?

Anyway, as [dma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55227/dma) points out in a comment, this solution suffers because "anything added to the code is going to be harder to remove for non-debugging builds". Agreed.

***Update 2***: Compiling this 4-line file with `-s`:

```
int                              foo1 = 111;
static int                       foo2 = 222;
static int volatile              foo3 = 333;
static int __attribute__((used)) foo4 = 444;
```

gives (abridged):

```
.globl foo1
    .data
foo1:
    .long   111
foo4:
    .long   444
```

That is, the variable `foo3`, using Clifford's suggestion of `volatile`, is ***compiled out***, while `foo4` is kept. (gcc 4.1.2)

***But,*** on the other hand, compiling:

```
void bar(void) {
    int                        bar2 = 222;
    int volatile               bar3 = 333;
    int __attribute__ ((used)) bar4 = 444;
}
```

gives:

> warning: 'used' attribute ignored

***and:***

```
movl    $333, -4(%ebp)
```

So this is the reverse: `volatile` works and `__attribute__ ((used))` doesn't (perhaps expected, since `bar4` is not `static`).

Comment: For debugging, it's going to be better to adjust the command-line of the compiler. Anything added to the code is going to be harder to remove for non-debugging builds.

Comment: @dma: in some cases the selectivity of this method may be an advantage.  For removal, you could use the same pattern as in my answer, only for the attribute instead.  An important thing to note is that this applies only to variables with static storage class (i.e. globals and explicitly static variables).